# How can i optimise javascript pagination so that it works for any number of pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create Vanilla Javascript Pagination and i have a problem because it looks like my pagination is only working when there is 7 pages,when that number switches there are small bugs but i cant find a way to optimise better my code and to make the code be usable for any number of page.Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
      crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="blog-listing">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <input
              type="search"
              class="inputs"
              id="searcher"
              placeholder="Search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="BLOG_POST" />
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="LISTING_PAGE" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-6"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="blogs"></div>
        <div id="blog-pagination"></div>
        <div id="buttons"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.blog-listing {
  padding: 200px 0px;
}
.blog-listing input {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 40.5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.blog-listing input::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #19212f;
}
.blog-listing input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #19212f;
}
.blog-listing input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: #19212f;
}
.blog-listing__card {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.105633);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.blog-listing__card__image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.blog-listing__card__text {
  padding: 30px 40px 60px;
}
.blog-listing__card__text a {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #089fd9;
}
.blog-listing__card__text p {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #878787;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.blog-listing__card__text h1,
.blog-listing__card__text h2,
.blog-listing__card__text h3 {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 53px;
  letter-spacing: -0.392857px;
  color: #293241;
}
.blog-listing__card__divider {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.blog-listing__card.is-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
.blog-listing__card__topics ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.blog-listing__card__topics ul li a {
  font-family: "Abel";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #293241;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.blog-tag-filter {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blog-tag-filter {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.blog-tag-filter__title {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.blog-tag-filter__select-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.blog-tag-filter__select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.25rem 4.5rem 1.25rem 2.75rem;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 40.5px;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #19212f;
}

.blog-tag-filter__select-wrapper:after {
  color: #19212f;
  content: "▾";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.7rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#blog-pagination {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0px;
}

#buttons input {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.75px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: #089fd9;
}

#buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  background-color: #089fd9 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
  color: gray !important;
  background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
}

.none {
  display: none !important;
}
```

JS

```
let allBlogs = [];
allBlogs.length = 14;

let blog_div = document.getElementById("blogs");
let blogTagSelect = document.querySelector("#tag-select");
// let selectedItem = blogTagSelect.options[blogTagSelect.selectedIndex];
let countList = new Array();
let addPageList = new Array();
let presentPage = 1;
let countPerEachPage = 2;
let countOfPages = 0;
let buttons = document.getElementById("buttons");

function prepareList() {
  let inputFirst = document.createElement("input");
  inputFirst.setAttribute("type", "button");
  inputFirst.setAttribute("id", "first");
  inputFirst.setAttribute("value", "first");
  inputFirst.onclick = function () {
    presentPage = 1;
    loadMyPaginationList();
    for (let i = 0; i < pageBtns.length; i++) {
      pageBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
      if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == presentPage) {
        pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
      }
      if (pageBtns[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        pageBtns[i].classList.remove("none");
        for (let j = 0; j < pageBtns.length; j++) {
          if (pageBtns[j].value > 2) {
            pageBtns[j].classList.add("none");
            pageBtns[1].classList.remove("none");
            if (pageBtns[j].value > pageBtns.length - 2) {
              pageBtns[j].classList.remove("none");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  let inputPrevious = document.createElement("input");
  inputPrevious.setAttribute("type", "button");
  inputPrevious.setAttribute("id", "previous");
  inputPrevious.setAttribute("value", "previous");
  inputPrevious.onclick = function () {
    presentPage -= 1;
    loadMyPaginationList();
    for (let i = 0; i < pageBtns.length; i++) {
      pageBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
      if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == presentPage) {
        pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
        pageBtns[i].classList.remove("none");

        if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) < Math.ceil(pageBtns.length / 2)) {
          pageBtns[i + 2].classList.add("none");
        }

        if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == pageBtns.length - 2) {
          pageBtns[i - 1].classList.remove("none");
          for (let j = 0; j < pageBtns.length; j++) {
            if (pageBtns[j].value < Math.ceil(pageBtns.length / 2)) {
              pageBtns[j].classList.add("none");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  buttons.appendChild(inputFirst);
  buttons.appendChild(inputPrevious);

  for (count = 0; count < allBlogs.length; count++) {
    countList.push(count);
  }
  countOfPages = getCountOfPages();
  for (let i = 1; i <= countOfPages; i++) {
    let inputButton = document.createElement("input");
    inputButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    inputButton.setAttribute("class", "page-buttons");
    inputButton.setAttribute("value", i);
    inputButton.onclick = function () {
      presentPage = Number(inputButton.value);
      loadMyPaginationList();
    };
    buttons.appendChild(inputButton);

    if (
      inputButton.value > presentPage + 1 &&
      inputButton.value < countOfPages - 1
    ) {
      inputButton.classList.add("none");
      if (Number(inputButton.value) == countOfPages - 2) {
        let Dots = document.createElement("input");
        Dots.setAttribute("value", "...");
        Dots.setAttribute("class", "dots");
        buttons.appendChild(Dots);
      }
    }
  }

  let inputNext = document.createElement("input");
  inputNext.setAttribute("type", "button");
  inputNext.setAttribute("id", "next");
  inputNext.setAttribute("value", "next");
  inputNext.onclick = function () {
    presentPage += 1;
    loadMyPaginationList();
    for (let i = 0; i < pageBtns.length; i++) {
      pageBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
      if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == presentPage) {
        pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
        if (pageBtns[i + 1] != null) {
          pageBtns[i + 1].classList.remove("none");
          pageBtns[i - 1].classList.add("none");
        }
        if (Number(pageBtns[i].value - 1) >= Math.ceil(pageBtns.length / 2)) {
          pageBtns[i - 1].classList.remove("none");
        } else {
          pageBtns[i - 1].classList.add("none");
        }

        if (pageBtns[i].classList.contains("active")) {
          pageBtns[i].classList.remove("none");
          if (pageBtns[i - 2] != null) {
            pageBtns[i - 2].classList.add("none");
            if (pageBtns[i].value > Math.ceil(pageBtns.length / 2 + 1)) {
              pageBtns[i - 2].classList.remove("none");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  let inputLast = document.createElement("input");
  inputLast.setAttribute("type", "button");
  inputLast.setAttribute("id", "last");
  inputLast.setAttribute("value", "last");
  inputLast.onclick = function () {
    presentPage = countOfPages;
    loadMyPaginationList();
    for (let i = 0; i < pageBtns.length; i++) {
      pageBtns[i].classList.remove("active");
      if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == presentPage) {
        pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
      }
    }
  };

  buttons.appendChild(inputNext);
  buttons.appendChild(inputLast);

  let pageBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".page-buttons");
  for (let i = 0; i < pageBtns.length; i++) {
    if (Number(pageBtns[i].value) == presentPage) {
      pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
    }
    pageBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      if (current.length > 0) {
        current[0].classList.remove("active");
      }
      pageBtns[i].classList.add("active");
    });
  }
}

//function for creating how many how many number per each page
function getCountOfPages() {
  return Math.ceil(countList.length / countPerEachPage);
}

//function for creating how to move between the pages
function loadMyPaginationList() {
  let offset = (presentPage - 1) * countPerEachPage + 1 - 1;
  let start = (presentPage - 1) * countPerEachPage;
  let end = start + countPerEachPage;
  addPageList = countList.slice(start, end);
  createPageList();
  validatePageCount();
}
//function for adding numbers to each page
function createPageList() {
  blog_div.innerHTML = "";
  let indexEnd =
    presentPage * countPerEachPage <= allBlogs.length
      ? presentPage * countPerEachPage
      : allBlogs.length;
  for (let i = (presentPage - 1) * countPerEachPage; i < indexEnd; i++) {
    let bootstrapDiv = document.createElement("div");
    bootstrapDiv.classList = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12";
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList = "blog-listing__card";
    let cardImage = document.createElement("div");
    cardImage.classList = "blog-listing__card__image";
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "./Bitmap.svg");
    let cardText = document.createElement("div");
    cardText.classList = "blog-listing__card__text";
    let cardTitle = document.createElement("h2");
    cardTitle.innerText = `Naslov ${i}`;
    let textLink = document.createElement("a");
    textLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
    textLink.innerText = `Datum | Autor`;
    let textText = document.createElement("p");
    textText.innerText = `Opis`;
    let topics = document.createElement("div");
    topics.classList = "blog-listing__card__topics";
    let topicList = document.createElement("ul");
    let topicLi = document.createElement("li");
    let topicLink = document.createElement("a");
    topicLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
    topicLink.innerText = `Tagovi`;
    let divider = document.createElement("div");
    divider.classList = "blog-listing__card__divider";
    cardText.appendChild(cardTitle);
    cardText.appendChild(textLink);
    cardText.appendChild(textText);
    link.appendChild(img);
    cardImage.appendChild(link);
    topicLi.appendChild(topicLink);
    topicList.appendChild(topicLi);
    topics.appendChild(topicList);
    card.appendChild(cardImage);
    card.appendChild(cardText);
    card.appendChild(topics);
    card.appendChild(divider);
    bootstrapDiv.appendChild(card);
    blog_div.appendChild(bootstrapDiv);
  }
}
//function for validating real time condition like if move to last page, last page disabled etc
function validatePageCount() {
  let inputFirst = document.getElementById("first");
  let inputPrevious = document.getElementById("previous");
  let inputNext = document.getElementById("next");
  let inputLast = document.getElementById("last");
  let PBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".page-buttons");

  if (presentPage == 1) {
    inputFirst.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    inputPrevious.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  } else {
    inputFirst.removeAttribute("disabled");
    inputPrevious.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }

  if (presentPage == countOfPages) {
    inputNext.setAttribute("disabled", "");
    inputLast.setAttribute("disabled", "");
  } else {
    inputNext.removeAttribute("disabled");
    inputLast.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
//function for loading pagination functionality
function loadMyPagination() {
  prepareList();
  loadMyPaginationList();
}

window.onload = loadMyPagination;

function liveSearch() {
  let searchQuery = document.getElementById("searcher").value;
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".blog-listing__card");
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    if (cards[i].querySelector("h1, h2, h3").outerText !== null) {
      if (
        cards[i]
          .querySelector("h1, h2, h3")
          .outerText.toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        cards[i].classList.remove("is-hidden");
      } else {
        cards[i].classList.add("is-hidden");
      }
    }
  }
}

let typingTimer;
let typeInterval = 300;
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searcher");
searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(liveSearch, typeInterval);
});

function blogFilter() {
  if (document.querySelector("#tag-select") !== null) {
    let blog_div = document.getElementById("blogs");
    let blogTagSelect = document.querySelector("#tag-select");
    let selectedItem = blogTagSelect.options[blogTagSelect.selectedIndex];
    if (selectedItem.innerText == "Tags") {
      blog_div.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < allBlogs.length; i++) {
        let bootstrapDiv = document.createElement("div");
        bootstrapDiv.classList = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12";
        let card = document.createElement("div");
        card.classList = "blog-listing__card";
        let cardImage = document.createElement("div");
        cardImage.classList = "blog-listing__card__image";
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", "#");
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "./Bitmap.svg");
        let cardText = document.createElement("div");
        cardText.classList = "blog-listing__card__text";
        let cardTitle = document.createElement("h2");
        cardTitle.innerText = `Naslov ${i}`;
        let textLink = document.createElement("a");
        textLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
        textLink.innerText = `Datum | Autor`;
        let textText = document.createElement("p");
        textText.innerText = `Opis`;
        let topics = document.createElement("div");
        topics.classList = "blog-listing__card__topics";
        let topicList = document.createElement("ul");
        let topicLi = document.createElement("li");
        let topicLink = document.createElement("a");
        topicLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
        topicLink.innerText = `Tagovi`;
        let divider = document.createElement("div");
        divider.classList = "blog-listing__card__divider";
        cardText.appendChild(cardTitle);
        cardText.appendChild(textLink);
        cardText.appendChild(textText);
        link.appendChild(img);
        cardImage.appendChild(link);
        topicLi.appendChild(topicLink);
        topicList.appendChild(topicLi);
        topics.appendChild(topicList);
        card.appendChild(cardImage);
        card.appendChild(cardText);
        card.appendChild(topics);
        card.appendChild(divider);
        bootstrapDiv.appendChild(card);
        blog_div.appendChild(bootstrapDiv);
      }
    } else {
      blog_div.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < allBlogs.length; i++) {
        if (allBlogs[i].topic.includes(selectedItem.innerText)) {
          let bootstrapDiv = document.createElement("div");
          bootstrapDiv.classList = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12";
          let card = document.createElement("div");
          card.classList = "blog-listing__card";
          let cardImage = document.createElement("div");
          cardImage.classList = "blog-listing__card__image";
          let link = document.createElement("a");
          link.setAttribute("href", "#");
          let img = document.createElement("img");
          img.setAttribute("src", "./Bitmap.svg");
          let cardText = document.createElement("div");
          cardText.classList = "blog-listing__card__text";
          let cardTitle = document.createElement("h2");
          cardTitle.innerText = `Naslov ${i}`;
          let textLink = document.createElement("a");
          textLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
          textLink.innerText = `Datum | Autor`;
          let textText = document.createElement("p");
          textText.innerText = `Opis`;
          let topics = document.createElement("div");
          topics.classList = "blog-listing__card__topics";
          let topicList = document.createElement("ul");
          let topicLi = document.createElement("li");
          let topicLink = document.createElement("a");
          topicLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
          topicLink.innerText = `Tagovi`;
          let divider = document.createElement("div");
          divider.classList = "blog-listing__card__divider";
          cardText.appendChild(cardTitle);
          cardText.appendChild(textLink);
          cardText.appendChild(textText);
          link.appendChild(img);
          cardImage.appendChild(link);
          topicLi.appendChild(topicLink);
          topicList.appendChild(topicLi);
          topics.appendChild(topicList);
          card.appendChild(cardImage);
          card.appendChild(cardText);
          card.appendChild(topics);
          card.appendChild(divider);
          bootstrapDiv.appendChild(card);
          blog_div.appendChild(bootstrapDiv);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// blogTagSelect.addEventListener("change", blogFilter);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3H2N.png

I tried to optimise the code to work for all numbers of pages but I can't find a good solution

Comment: There is a lot of element construction in that code, is it really all necessary to demonstrate this problem? Please take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with a focus on the **minimal**) and ideally include a snippet so we can see the problem in action

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

For the pagination numbers and links, try something like this:

```
 //Element to append page numbers
 let paginationElem = document.getElementbyId("yourPageElementIdHere")

 //Your blogs
 let allBlogs = []

 //Get number of pages required
 let pagesNeeded = allBlogs.length / <number of entries per-page> //May need to be rounded

 //Create numbered link for each page. Begin loop at 0 to avoid printing first page as "0"
 for(i=1; i < pagesNeeded + 1; i++) {
    let pageNum = document.createElement("a").innerHTML = i
    pageNum.html = "" //your link to page here
    paginationElem.append(pageNum)
 }
```

In case you're wondering how to select and display the relevant articles on each page, you'll need to get the clicked number of the page - as search param (?pageNum=4) in  link, perhaps - then create a loop, which will store the correct articles in an array. Something like this should work:

```
 //Your articles in an array
 let allBlogs = []

 let pageNum = //Get value from search param

 // Array for articles to display on desired page
 let articlesToDisplay = []

 //Set default for first page
 let firstArticle = 0

 // Set number of first article/starting point for loop
 if(pageNum != 0) {
     firstArticle = (pageNum - 1) * 10 //or other number of articles per page
 }

 // Loop through articles, beginning at first article,for desired number of articles (10, here). Push into array.
 for(i=firstArticle; i < firstArticle + 10; i++) {
   articles.push(allBlogs[i])
 }
```

You can loop through the articlesToDislay array, or create elements in the final loop and have these appended to somewhere in the document.